# repeatedly "getting" a changing int

Tags: java, swing, timer

The problem is that I'm not getting any errors, but the timer is not being added to the frame.

Lets say I've got three classes: InFrameClock, TimeKeeper and TwoPlayer

TimeKeeper contains a swing timer that increments an int "counter" every second:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimeKeeper extends JPanel {
private Timer timer;
private int delay = 1000; // every 1 second
private ActionListener action;
private int counter = 0;

public TimeKeeper() {

    action = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    counter++;

        };
        };
}

public boolean isTimerRunning() {
    return timer != null && timer.isRunning();
}

public void startTimer() {
    timer = new Timer(delay, action);
    timer.setInitialDelay(0);
    timer.start();
}

public void stopTimer() {
    if (timer != null && timer.isRunning()) {
        timer.stop();
        timer = null;
        counter = 0;
    }
}

public int getCounter() {
    return counter;
}

public void setCounter(int counter) {
    this.counter = counter;
}
}
```

^Clearly these are used elsewhere, but I'll get to that in a bit

The TwoPlayer class starts and stops the timer:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TwoPlayer {
private JFrame mainFrame;
private TimeKeeper myTimeKeeper;

public TwoPlayer() {
    mainFrame = new JFrame("Two Player");
    mainFrame.setSize(325, 135);
    mainFrame.setLocation(600, 300);
    mainFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    myTimeKeeper = new TimeKeeper();

    JButton button1 = new JButton("Start/Stop");
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (myTimeKeeper.isTimerRunning()) {
                myTimeKeeper.stopTimer();
            } 
            else {
                    myTimeKeeper.startTimer();
                }
        }
            });

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    InFrameClock clock = new InFrameClock(myTimeKeeper);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    mainFrame.add(button1);
    mainFrame.add(clock);
}
}
```

The object "clock" which is added to the frame above comes from the following class:

```
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class InFrameClock extends JPanel{
private JLabel clock = new JLabel();
private int timeSec;
private int timeMin;

TimeKeeper myTimeKeeper;

public InFrameClock(TimeKeeper timeKeeper){
    this.myTimeKeeper = timeKeeper;
    int clockVal = timeKeeper.getCounter(); 
    clock.setText(String.valueOf(clockVal));

    while (clockVal <= 0){
        clockVal = timeKeeper.getCounter();

    if(clockVal >= 60){
        timeSec = clockVal % 60;
        timeMin = (clockVal - timeSec)/60;
        clock.setText(String.valueOf(timeMin) +
        ":" + String.valueOf(timeSec));
    }   
    else{
        clock.setText(String.valueOf(clockVal));
    }

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    add(clock); 

    }
}   
}
```

What I think I am doing: Initializing counter to 0 in TimeKeeper, starting TimeKeeper with the start button in TwoPlayer, and getting the value of counter for as long as it is less than or equal to 0.

The idea here is that I create a "clock" in my window which displays the value of time since starting in a minutes and seconds format.

Comment: Could you please clarify what your question here is?

Comment: Oh! sorry, the problem is that I'm not getting any errors, but the timer is not being added to the frame

Comment: Your code has bugs in it preventing us from copying and pasting it and running it. Better if you could coalesce the code into a valid [mcve] and save us the trouble of trying to debug bunches of errors.

Comment: Will fix the code, couldn't tell in the editor.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels should be bug free now

Comment: @JoopEggen Thats essentially what I missed in my MCVE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a while loop running on the Swing event thread and freezing it. Get this off the event thread. Better still, change your code so that you don't need that while loop. Instead either use your Swing Timer's actionPerformed as the event to change the state of the view, or else use an observer pattern to have the view be notified of changes to the timer's counter.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense that the while loop was holding everything up, not mentioning the bad placement.

Answer (score 4):

As clockVal is the counter increased by 1 from 0, the while condition will be fullfilled only once at the beginning

```
while (clockVal <= 0){
```

A bit further

```
if(clockVal >= 60){
```

cannot become easily become true, as milliseconds passed between `<= 0` and `<= 60`.

Also a busy loop in a constructor does not make sense; is not the intended event based GUI model.